# Custom Checkbox Group component value setter works in Playground but fails in Live

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a custom checkbox button group component that works fine except for the fact that when I set it's value property to '' it should clear all selected options. This functionality works in the LWC playground perfectly, but when I bring it into a Salesforce org I have to set the value to '' twice in order for it to produce the desired outcome.

**Example of component in use**

[image]

**checkboxButtonGroup.html**

```
<template>
<label class="slds-form-element__label">{label}</label>
<fieldset>
    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
        <template for:each={_options} for:item="option">
            <div key={option.label} class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-p-around_medium slds-size_1-of-3">
                <lightning-input type="checkbox-button" label={option.label} checked={option.checked} disabled={option.disabled} value={option.value}></lightning-input>
                <div class="slds-p-left_medium">{option.label}</div>
            </div>
        </template>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

**checboxButtonGroup.js**

```
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';

export default class CheckboxButtonGroup extends LightningElement {
@api label;
@api
set options(value) {
    this._options = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value));
}
get options() {
    return this._options;
}
@track _options;
@api
set value(value) {
    this._values = value.split(',');
    this.convertValueToCheckedOptions();
}
get value() {
    return this.getValues().join(',');
}
@api defaultValue;
convertValueToCheckedOptions() {
    this._options.forEach((x) => {
        x.checked = (this._values.indexOf(x.label) > -1);
    });
}
getValues() {
    const values = [];
    this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input').forEach((x)=>{
        if(x.checked) values.push(x.value);
    })
    return values;
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you post the working Playground link ?

Comment: Why don't you just use lightning-checkbox-group, though? What's the need for a custom component?

Comment: @SahilMalhotra never shared a playground app before so I am assuming I just need to copy the url: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/8WS_I274/9/edit

Comment: @sfdcfox I need the checkbox button input control as it is far easier for touch devices to work with than a normal checkbox control.